# Summarizing a python list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, summarize

**Given the following python list of dictionaries:**

```
product_issues = [

{'product':'battery',
'High': 0,
'Med':1
'Low':0
 '},

{'product':'battery',
'High': 1,
'Med':0
'Low':0
 '},

{'product':'battery',
'High': 1,
'Med':0
'Low':0
 '},


{'product':'tape',
'High': 1,
'Med':0
'Low':0
 '},

{'product':'tape',
'High': 1,
'Med':0
'Low':0
 '},

]
```

**Produce the following summary of H/M/L per product:**

```
product_issues_summary = [

{'product':'battery',
'High': 2,
'Med':1
'Low':0
 '},

{'product':'tape',
'High': 2,
'Med':0
'Low':0
 '},
]
```

Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. This seems like a homework question. Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) under "Asking about homework". See [ask] for other tips.

Comment: just give an answer so complex they can't use it..so they're forced to understand it and re-write it themselves XD

Comment: also the dict is improperly formatted

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's something you can try. It uses a `collections.defaultdict` or `collections.Counter` to count `High`, `Med` and `Low` for each `product`, then merges the results at the end.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

product_issues = [
    {"product": "battery", "High": 0, "Med": 1, "Low": 0},
    {"product": "battery", "High": 1, "Med": 0, "Low": 0},
    {"product": "battery", "High": 1, "Med": 0, "Low": 0},
    {"product": "tape", "High": 1, "Med": 0, "Low": 0},
    {"product": "tape", "High": 1, "Med": 0, "Low": 0},
]

d = defaultdict(Counter)
for product in product_issues:
    levels = {k: v for k, v in product.items() if k != "product"}
    d[product["product"]].update(levels)

print([{**{"product": k}, **v} for k, v in d.items()])
```

**Summarized results:**

```
[{'product': 'battery', 'High': 2, 'Med': 1, 'Low': 0}, {'product': 'tape', 'High': 2, 'Med': 0, 'Low': 0}]
```